# Show that in this right angled triangle,$x^0+y^0=z^0$....

Tags: geometry, triangles

> $ABC$ is a right angled triangle at $B$.On side $AB$ points $E$ and $F$ are taken such that $AE=EF=FB=BC$.Let, $\angle CAE=x^0$,$\angle CEF=y^0$ and $\angle CFB=z^0$.
>   Now,prove that $x^0+y^0=z^0$.

[image]

**I can do it using inverse trig functions and finding the angles.But I would like a more geometrical proof.**

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This is NOT yet possible unless some other conditions are met.

Comment: @Mick-Please try to disprove it....

Comment: Just draw any arbitrary right angled triangle with the said conditions. Then measure the said angles.

Comment: @Mick Note $FB=BC$. The picture is drawn _very_ not to scale.

Comment: @Wojowu-It's not his fault.I had not added that condition before....

Comment: It can be shown that $x+y+z=90$, if that's what you meant.

Comment: @Cataline as shown there? I think that solves the problem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5evLoL0xwg

Comment: @Baconaro yes, that's where I got it from.

Comment: @Wojowu As far as I can remember, that was not included in the original version. That was why I mentioned that the question need some other conditions in my first comment.

Comment: @Baconaro-Thanks...I think this will solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Draw a picture like this. Observe that the indicated angles are equal to $x$ and $y$ and that triangle $XYZ$ is right-angled and isosceles.

[image]

Comment: In OP question, AB=3BC. But in this diagram $AB=\sqrt{5},BC=\sqrt{10}.$

Comment: I'll change the letters in my drawing to X, Y, Z to not confuse people